# Showing prompt from ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line

I am running this command:
`ssh -i key user@domainname 'bash -l -c "command"'`

The `command` script calls on another script that asks for input at some point. The problem is that the prompt for the command asking for input comes *after* I type in the answer to the prompt, which obviously is bad because I don't know what I am responding to. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try allocating a terminal on the ssh host:

```
ssh -t -i key user@domainname 'bash -l -c "command"'
```